# PHP - Insert SQL on while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I generated a random monster team from a table, and limited by 6. Now, I also want to insert the team into user_team which contains the fields
    m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6

Those represent Monster 1 to Monster 6. Now when I try to insert the generated monsters into the team, only the last Monster seems to be inserting into it while I all of my monsters to be inserted.
http://prntscr.com/8zrj2

```
$sql = "SELECT * from monsterdata ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
// this checks if you have a result
if ($result == null) echo "No result";
else {  
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != false) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
{
// html code here
}
}
```

the Insert statement is 
`$monster = $row['id'];
        $sql = "INSERT into user_team(m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6) VALUES('$monster','$monster','$monster','$monster','$monster','$monster')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);`

Just don't know where/how to place it so it inserts the right values into the right columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I would push the ids into an array and then use that like so:

```
$monsterIds = array();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false) {
    $monsterIds[] = $row['id'];
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_team (m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6) VALUES ('{$monsterIds[0]}', '{$monsterIds[2]}', '{$monsterIds[3]}', '{$monsterIds[4]}', '{$monsterIds[5]}')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, don't forget to use the triple equals when comparing row results so that you don't get caught by a weird bug where things evaluate to false that aren't actually false (=== is the way to go with many functions which might return either an array, integer, or a boolean depending on the outcome).

The values will be placed in the columns in the order they are supplied.

Comment: I tried that, what happened was this.
http://prntscr.com/8zst9
That was supposed to be a single one, and it doesn't insert all 6! :( Thanks for help though!

Comment: forgot to mention it gives a Undefined offset: for 1 to 5 @LosFrijoles

Comment: This is meant to completely replace your while loop. It looks like from your paste that you are running this partially inside a while loop (hence the diagonal pattern of getting ids). The undefined offset is happening because it hasn't got to the end yet. The loop has to complete before you can do anything with the data.

Comment: yep, I went through my code and fixed it! thank you again @losfrijoles

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example using PDO (php library):

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
$webContractList=$DBH->query('SELECT id,nume,data FROM user2')->fetchAll();

$STH=$DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO user (id,nume,data) VALUES (:id ,:nume , :data)");

foreach ($webContractList as $item){           
    $STH->execute(array(':id'=>$item['id'],
                ':nume'=>$item['nume'],
                ':data'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item['data']))));
}
```